# Two different slots for the same signal

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots

When m_serverClientControl emits finishedRunning() on its thread, How can I tell what slot gets executed first/last in the main thread? How do the slots get queued in a situation like this? I'm confused as how Qt places slot events on the thread event queue. I have read the document ion but I'm still a tad bit confused.

```
connect( m_serverClientControl, SIGNAL( finishedRunning() ), m_serverClientControl, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
connect( m_serverClientControl, SIGNAL( finishedRunning() ), this, SLOT( finishedRunningEmited() ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt 4.7 docs:

> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be
>   executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected,
>   when the signal is emitted.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/signalsandslots.html#signals

So in your case `finishedRunningEmited()` should be called after `deleteLater()`.